Applying the Jordan Lemma to the Integral $ I = \int_{C(R)} \frac{e^{-ipz}}{z} \, dz $
I want to solve the integral
$$
I = \int_{C(R)} \frac{e^{-ipz}}{z} \, dz
$$
where ( C(R) ) is a circular arc centered at the origin with radius ( R ), and it lies in the upper half plane and ( $R \to \infty$ ), with ( $p > 0$ ). I want to use Jordan's Lemma firstly, but Jordan's Lemma need that ($ p > 0 $).
Then I consider another theorem, maybe called the Large Arc Lemma, if ( $ zf(z)$ ) uniformly converges to a constant ( K ) as ( $|z| \to \infty $), then the integral of ( $f(z)$ ) along a circular arc ( C(R) ) centered at the origin with radius ( R ) and angle from $
\theta_1 \text{ to } \theta_2 
$$ :
$$
\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C(R)} f(z) \, dz = i(\theta_2 - \theta_1) K.
$
Now apply this theorem.$$
zf(z) = \frac{e^{-ipz}}{z} \cdot z = e^{-ipz}.
$$
Hence, ( $zf(z) \to 0 $) as ($ R \to \infty $),  This leads to:
$$
\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C(R)} \frac{e^{-ipz}}{z} \, dz = i(\theta_2 - \theta_1) \cdot 0 = 0.
$$
So I get  the integral should be 0.
However, The correct result is
$$
\int_{C(R)} \frac{e^{-ipz}}{z} \, dz = 2\pi i
$$
for any closed contour enclosing the origin, regardless of the radius ( R ), provided that ( $p > 0 \ $). Thus, the integral does not tend to zero as ( R $\to \infty $), and the result is ( $2\pi$ i ).
So why can't I use this "Large Arc Lemma"? And how to approach this problem.

is the arc a full circle? also, does it lie in the upper half plane?

$e^{-i pz}$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ as $|z|\to \infty$.

@Nick Castillo,  lie in the upper half plane

@raj Thanks, now I have another question, if z -> 0, then can I use the Small Arc Lemma, which is nearly the same as the Large Arc Lemma. It seems that e^-ipz -> 1 when z -> 0 It is at the C(r) ) that is a circular arc centered at the origin with radius ( r ) r -> 0

Maybe, there is a misprint and you have, with $\displaystyle p > 0$, $\displaystyle{\rm e}^{{\rm i}pz}$ instead.
